# ODE singular point

Tags: general-relativity, differential-equations, ads-cft

I want to study the equation of motion of a scalar field in the Schwarzschild $AdS_5$ black hole
$$\frac{\hat{\omega}^2\phi(\hat{z})}{(-1+\hat{z}^4)^2}+\frac{(3+\hat{z}^4)\phi(\hat{z})}{\hat{z}(-1+\hat{z}^4)}+\phi''(\hat{z})=0$$ where $\hat{\omega}=\omega/\pi T$ and $\hat{z}=z/z_H$ (T is the temperature of the black hole and $z_H$ the horizon) and reduce this equation to the equation of motion of the scalar field witout the black hole (pure AdS space), which reads $$\hat{\omega}^2\phi(\hat{z})-\frac{3}{\hat{z}}\phi'(\hat{z})+\phi''(\hat{z})=0$$. How do I perform that? I just want to look at the case where /≫1 and see what happens to the equation.

Comment: Any reference to this? What does it mean to go from Schwarzschild-AdS to AdS? As in, is there a background or reason for this? (I'm somewhat naive about this!) Also tell me what the things are, I am bad with notations and things.

Comment: What is $\hat\omega$? What is $\hat z$? It looks to me like you just take $\hat z\ll 1$ to get from the first equation to the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue really is, all said and done you're just asking to solve a more or less run of the mill ODE. What seems to be catching you up here physics wise?

Comment: The solutions are linear combinations of Bessel functions with modified arguments and factor functions. Look at eq (6) and (7) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html